# Is there an opensource framework/library for allowing dynamic manipulation of grid layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Normally when I make a website in HTML, I use Twitter Bootstrap grid and specify the layout using "container", "row" and "span" and I place all my content inside these.

I am looking for a mechanism to create these layouts from within a browser window without having to write code by just clicking, resizing, dragging and dropping.

Somewhat like this - http://www.dynamicdashboards.net/

Comment: in my opinion, drag and drop WYSIWYG layout design is a no no in html/css. Never seen a good implementation. If it also can be flex, try www.genericframe.com